# Android - Store Image to gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I am making an app which allows the user to change the camera's preview size and take pictures which will be saved to the device's gallery, here is my problem, it's that the picture is saved to the private dir of the app and it doesn't appear on the gallery. Here is my implementation logic :

Permissions in manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here I create and store file on the private directory:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if(pictureFile==null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Error creating media file, check storage permission: ");
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            galleryAddPic(pictureFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

This is the method which should save the picture to the gallery:

```
private void galleryAddPic(File pictureFile){
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri =  Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

This method is executed but still cannot see the result in the gallery....

Comment: Is your **pictureFile** accessible to MediaScanner? If it is, you probably can see it in gallery after device power off/on.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to scan every time when you storing images to private folder you need to call following method.

```
public static void reScanMediaDirectory(Context context, String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context, new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });
}
```

> where path is new file path for appearing in gallery.